# React JS : FirebaseUI auth persistence works on Firefox Mobile not Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I use react and redux 
and FirebaseUI behaves in weird ways

it works perfectly in 
Desktop-All Browsers
Mobile (tested with multiple Android phones) - Firefox and Opera **But Not in Chrome**

When I log in with FirebaseUI, it logs in and logs out the very next instant

I have no clue what is happening

I check for auth very next to the very first index file

**App.js**

```js
componentWillMount = () => {

  const {
    props
  } = this
  console.log('userid', props.userid);
  this.unsubscribeAuthListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      //  Save user data in redux store and set auth state as true
      store.dispatch(signIn(user))

      const userid = user.uid.toString()

      {
        // .......Listen to a firestore Document for document changes
      }
    } else {
      //Set auth state in redux to false
      store.dispatch(signOut())

    }

  });
  // Get location(city) of the user
  this.ipLookUp()

}



componentWillUnmount = () => {

  this.unsubscribeAuthListener();
}

  render() {
      return (

        <div>
             <LoginPage/>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

**LoginPage.js** -  Gets props.isauthed from another file where redux sends it

```js
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  uiConfig = {
    // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.

    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read',
        ],
        customParameters: {
          // Forces account selection even when one account
          // is available.
          prompt: 'select_account'
        }
      },
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        scopes: [
          'public_profile',
          'email',
          'user_likes',
          'user_friends',
          'user_birthday',
        ],

      },
    ],
    callbacks: {

      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async function(authResult, redirectUrl) {

        console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~______AuthResult________~~~~~~~~~~~~',authResult)
        store.dispatch(AddBasicData(authResult))

      },
      // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
      signInSuccess: () => false
    }
  };



  render() {
    console.log('Check If Props Change in Render', this.props.isauthed)
    if (!this.props.isauthed) {
      return (

        <div>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <p>Please sign-in:</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />

        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
          <p>User Signed IN</p>
      
    )
  }
}





export default LoginPage;
```

**is this because Chrome is actively deleting cache to save memory**